# delaying excel calculations during interop C#

Tags: c#, excel, com-interop, delayed-execution

I have to input several hundred cells into an excel sheet from a C# program.  Each time I set a cell or a range, excel slowly responds... presumably updating various outputs between each input I add.  Is there a way to disable calculations from my C# program, and re-enable it after I am done setting cells and ready to read the outputs?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, set the `Application.Calculation` to `xlCalculationManual`, then back to `xlCalculationAutomatic`.

You can also consider setting `Application.ScreenUpdating` to `false` and then back to `true`.