# VBA code optimization

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of VBA codes which work really perfectly with around of 20 000 x 16 cells. 
However, I need to use the codes with max 80 000 x 16 cells.

I have identified two types of codes which run really slow:

```
    c = 2 'this is the first row where your data will output
    d = 2 'this is the first row where you want to check for data

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Do Until Range("A" & c) = "" 'This will loop until column U is empty, set the column to whatever you want
                            'but it cannot have blanks in it, or it will stop looping. Choose a column that is
                            'always going to have data in it.

     ws1.Range("U" & d).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-20] & RIGHT(""0000"" & RC[-14], 6)"

     c = c + 1 'Advances a and b when there is a matching case
     d = d + 1

    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub 

Sub OpenValue()    
    Dim l As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim m As Integer

    m = Sheets("Input").Range("AC:AC").End(xlDown).Row

    For l = 2 To m

    If Range("AC" & l) = "Delievered" Then
       Range("AD" & l) = 0

    ElseIf Range("AC" & l) = "Cancelled" Then
       Range("AD" & l) = 0

    Else
      Range("AD" & l) = Val(Range("Z" & l)) * Val(Range("J" & l))

         End If

    Next

End Sub
```

What can I do to poptimize them ....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4259806/11683

Comment: Use `Cells` instead of `Range`, so you can avoid the string concatenation (ex. : `Cells(l, 30)` instead of `Range("AD" & l)`)

Comment: This should be in CodeReview.SE, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Question belongs on Code Review

Answer (score 1):

The link provided by @GSerg is an awesome way to cut the running time of your script down. I found myself using:

- `Application.ScreenUpdating` set to False
- `Application.Calculation` set to `xlCalculationManual`
- `Application.EnableEvents` set to False
- `Application.DisplayAlerts` set to False

so often that I combined them into a single public subroutine. @Garys-Student provided the inspiration:

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'INPUT         : True or False (i.e. fast or slow)
'DESCRIPTION   : this sub turns off screen updating and alarms then
'                sets calculations to manual
'
Public Sub GoFast(OnOrOff As Boolean)
    Dim CalcMode As XlCalculation
    CalcMode = Application.Calculation
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = Not OnOrOff
        .EnableEvents = Not OnOrOff
        .DisplayAlerts = Not OnOrOff
        If OnOrOff Then
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Else
            .Calculation = CalcMode
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

In practice, you can now add the one-liner:

```
Call GoFast(True)
```

at the beginning of your script as part of the setup, then add:

```
Call GoFast(False)
```

at the end of your script as part of the teardown. Modify as you see fit!

Answer (score 0):

The `Do Until` can be replaced with a one liner:

```
ws1.Range("A2", ws1.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Offset(0,20).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=RC[-20] & RIGHT(""0000"" & RC[-14], 6)"
```

Note that this will fail if `A3` is empty. If you have headers in row 1 you can change the second `A2` to `A1`.

For the other `Sub` I'm not sure if you are doing something special with `Val` but if not you could change it to something similar:

```
Sub OpenValue()

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Sheets("Input").Range("AD2:AD" & Sheets("Input").Range("AC1").End(xlDown).Row)
    With r
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[-1]=""Delivered"",RC[-1]=""Cancelled""),0,RC10*RC26"
        'If you want these as values uncomment the following lines
        '.Calculate
        '.Copy
        '.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Sprinkle `Application` stuff around if needed (Calculation, ScreenUpdating, DisplayAlerts, EnableEvents).

### Why is this faster:

To put it simply, VBA and Excel have to open a 'channel' to communicate between each other and this costs some time. So looping through a Range and adding formulas one-by-one is much slower for large ranges than doing it all at once since you'll only open the 'channel' once.